# data to specific points in a gauge

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am working on a dashboard skin that recieves data from a game through a plugin.
now have i stumbled upon a problem. the rpm gauge isn't perfect. the 0 to 5 on the gauge is on a smaller angle than 5 to 10 is. now am i trying to find a way to set 5 to a specific angle. i have a min angle of -125 and a max angle of 125. so 0 = -125 and 5 = -90 but 10 = -40 so the angle from 0 to 5 is 35 degrees and from 5 to 10 it is 50 degrees.
i only have a html code and a css (css for the gauge needle placement)

html:

```
<div class="truck-engineRpm gauges" data-type="meter" data-min="0"  data-max="25" data-min-angle="-125"  data-max-angle="90"></div>
```

css:

```
.truck-engineRpm {
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1816px;
    top: 391px;
    width: 40px;
    height: 391px;
    background-image: url("images/needle.png");
    transform: rotate(-125deg);
    transform-origin: 50% 322px;
    transition: 300ms linear;
}
```

this picture shows the different degrees between the points. the gauge i created is linear. but this gauge i have isn't linear. when giving the gauge a value through javascript it doesn't line up with the data on the gauge

https://live.staticflickr.com/65535/50929988042_b30ff30c77_z.jpg

i want to create a non linear gauge with data set a fixed angles. what i have now is a linear gauge with only min/max data and angles

---- i got it fixed ----

i took the value of where the needle was pointing (so when the needle was pointing at 5, the data was 350 rpm), made some calculations to find out what number i needed to calculate the game rpms with to display it correctly.
Javascript code:

```
    var Rpm = data.truck.engineRpm;
    var RpmCalc = data.truck.engineRpm
    var RpmRange1 = data.truck.engineRpm;
    var RpmRange2 = data.truck.engineRpm - 500;
    var RpmRange3 = data.truck.engineRpm - 1000;
    var RpmRange4 = data.truck.engineRpm - 1442;
    var RpmRange5 = data.truck.engineRpm - 1500;
    var RpmRange6 = data.truck.engineRpm - 2000;
    if (Rpm >= 0 && Rpm <= 500) {
        data.engineRpm = RpmCalc - (0.3 * RpmRange1);
    } else if (Rpm > 500 && Rpm <= 1000) {
        data.engineRpm = RpmCalc - (0.01 * RpmRange2 + 150);
    } else if (Rpm > 1000 && Rpm <= 1442) {
        data.engineRpm = RpmCalc + (0.35 * RpmRange3 - 155);
    } else if (Rpm > 1442 && Rpm <= 1500) {
        data.engineRpm = RpmCalc + (0.38 * RpmRange4);
    } else if (Rpm > 1500 && Rpm <= 2000) {
        data.engineRpm = RpmCalc + (0.08 * RpmRange5 + 22);
    } else if (Rpm > 2000 && Rpm <= 2500) {
        data.engineRpm = RpmCalc - (0.124 * RpmRange6 - 62);
    }
```

doesn't look pretty but if it works it works :)

Comment: could you produce a minimally reproducible example? not exactly sure what u mean :l

Comment: What do you receive as input? Are you given an RPM figure and required to output a valid gauge?

Comment: i recieve data as variables. so if the needle is at 5. the data i get is 500.

Comment: I'll use Excel as an example. You have two columns. The first contains RPM, the second has Needle Angle. Here are 6 entries from such a table. <0,214>, <500, 180>, <1000,130>, <1500, 64.5>, <2000,9>, <2500,-34> or <2500,326>.. You then work out where you are in that range and set the angle accordingly. If for instance, you got the figure of 800, you'd know it was between 500rpm and 1000rpm - two figures in your table. It is in fact, 3/5th of the way from 500 to 1000. So, 3/5ths of the angle between em. 500=180, 1000=130. Dif is 50, 3/5 of 50 is 30. Needle should be at 180-30 = 150 deg.

Comment: If you now check your gauge again, you'll find that 800 RPM *is* in fact at 150 deg.

Comment: but how do i set the right angles to the data. for instance if i manually set the rpm to 500rpm i need the angle to be at 90 degrees. figuring out what angles the rpm is isn't that hard cause i use paint.net to get the angles. but somehow i need to "bind" angles to the rpm data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example that shows what I was getting at. It's just a simple matter of mapping each unit within a range to another number.

```js
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

let gagueMap = [];

function onLoaded(evt) {
  let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
  canvas.style.backgroundImage = `url(${imgSrc})`;


  // setup the rpm->angle ranges for the gague
  gagueMap.push(new gagueRange(0, 500, 214, 180));
  gagueMap.push(new gagueRange(500, 1000, 180, 130));
  gagueMap.push(new gagueRange(1000, 1500, 130, 64.5));
  gagueMap.push(new gagueRange(1500, 2000, 64.5, 9));
  gagueMap.push(new gagueRange(2000, 2500, 9, -34));

  // handle changes to the slider
  document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', onRpmSliderChange, false);

  // make the slider think we changed it
  onRpmSliderChange.apply(document.querySelector('input'), null);
}

function onRpmSliderChange(evt) {
  let rpm = this.value;

  document.querySelector('#rpmOut').textContent = rpm;

  gagueMap.forEach(function(range) {
    if (range.contains(rpm))
      drawNeedle(range.map(rpm));
  });
}

function drawNeedle(angleDeg) {
  const needleLen = 52;

  let can = document.querySelector('canvas');
  let ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  let width = can.width,
    height = can.height;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  ctx.moveTo(width / 2, height / 2);

  let dx = Math.cos(angleDeg * 3.141 / 180.0) * needleLen;
  let dy = Math.sin(angleDeg * 3.141 / 180.0) * needleLen;

  ctx.lineTo(width / 2 + dx, height / 2 - dy);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

class gagueRange {
  // rpm1 <= rpm2
  constructor(rpm1, rpm2, angle1, angle2) {
    if (rpm1 <= rpm2) {
      this.rpm1 = rpm1;
      this.rpm2 = rpm2;
      this.angle1 = angle1;
      this.angle2 = angle2;
    } else // params back to front
    {
      this.rpm2 = rpm1;
      this.rpm1 = rpm2;
      this.angle2 = angle1;
      this.angle1 = angle2;
    }
  }
  contains(rpm) {
    if (rpm >= this.rpm1 && rpm <= this.rpm2)
      return true;
  }

  map(rpm) {
    if (this.contains(rpm) == false)
      return false;
    let proportion = (rpm - this.rpm1) / (this.rpm2 - this.rpm1);
    let deltaAngle = this.angle2 - this.angle1;
    let value = (proportion * deltaAngle) + this.angle1;
    return value;
  }
}

var imgSrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTg' +
             'iPz4KPHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMTI4IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEyOCIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIiB2aWV3Qm94' +
             'PSIwIDAgMzMuODcgMzMuODciIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+C' +
             'iA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxNi45MyIgY3k9IjE2LjkzIiByPSIxNi45MyIgZmlsbD0iIzJkMmQyZC' +
             'IvPgogPGcgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjZmZkNjE5IiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9Ii4yNjQ' +
             '2Ij4KICA8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxNi45MyIgY3k9IjE2LjkzIiByPSIyLjgwNiIvPgogIDxwYXRo' +
             'IGQ9Im0zLjg0NCAyNS45NGExNS44OCAxNS44OCAwIDAgMSAyLjUwNi0yMC45MSAxNS44OCAxN' +
             'S44OCAwIDAgMSAyMS4wNi0wLjAzNjc1IDE1Ljg4IDE1Ljg4IDAgMCAxIDIuNTc5IDIwLjkiLz' +
             '4KIDwvZz4KIDxnIGZpbGw9IiNmNmZmMTkiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2Y2ZmYxOSIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHR' +
             'oPSIuMjY0NnB4Ij4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJtMS4wMzkgMTYuOTNoMS4wNzUiLz4KICA8cGF0aCBk' +
             'PSJtMy43NjMgMjUuODMgMC44OTA4LTAuNjAxNCIvPgogIDxwYXRoIGQ9Im02LjcyMSA0Ljc0M' +
             'iAwLjY5MDkgMC44MjM0Ii8+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0ibTIzLjcyIDIuNTM1LTAuNDU3NyAwLjk3Mj' +
             'YiLz4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJtMzIuNjUgMTQuNDQtMS4wNjIgMC4xNjgxIi8+CiAgPHBhdGggZD0' +
             'ibTMwLjEzIDI1LjgyLTAuODkxMS0wLjYwMTEiLz4KIDwvZz4KIDx0ZXh0IHg9Ii02LjQyOTY4' +
             'OTkiIHk9IjIyLjg3NzczMyIgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZmYwMCIgZm9udC1mYW1pbHk9InNhbnMtc2Vya' +
             'WYiIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iNS4yOTJweCIgbGV0dGVyLXNwYWNpbmc9IjBweCIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjMD' +
             'AwMDAwIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9Ii4yNjQ2cHgiIHdvcmQtc3BhY2luZz0iMHB4IiBzdHlsZT0' +
             'iZm9udC12YXJpYW50LWNhcHM6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtdmFyaWFudC1saWdhdHVyZXM6bm9ybWFs' +
             'O2ZvbnQtdmFyaWFudC1udW1lcmljOm5vcm1hbDtsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoxMjUlIiB4bWw6c3BhY' +
             '2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48dHNwYW4geD0iLTYuNDI5Njg5OSIgeT0iMjIuODc3NzMzIiBmaWxsPS' +
             'IjZmZmZjAwIiBzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg9Ii4yNjQ2cHgiLz48L3RleHQ+CiA8ZyBmaWxsPSIjZmZ' +
             'kNjE5IiBmb250LWZhbWlseT0ic2Fucy1zZXJpZiIgbGV0dGVyLXNwYWNpbmc9IjBweCIgd29y' +
             'ZC1zcGFjaW5nPSIwcHgiPgogIDx0ZXh0IHg9IjUuOTgxMTA2MyIgeT0iMjUuMzQ0OTQiIGZvb' +
             'nQtc2l6ZT0iNS4yOTJweCIgc3R5bGU9ImZvbnQtdmFyaWFudC1jYXBzOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LX' +
             'ZhcmlhbnQtbGlnYXR1cmVzOm5vcm1hbDtmb250LXZhcmlhbnQtbnVtZXJpYzpub3JtYWw7bGl' +
             'uZS1oZWlnaHQ6MTI1JSIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSI+PHRzcGFuIHg9IjUuOTgxMTA2' +
             'MyIgeT0iMjUuMzQ0OTQiIGZpbGw9IiNmZmQ2MTkiIGZvbnQtZmFtaWx5PSJzYW5zLXNlcmlmI' +
             'iBmb250LXNpemU9IjIuODIycHgiIGZvbnQtc3R5bGU9Iml0YWxpYyIgZm9udC13ZWlnaHQ9Im' +
             'JvbGQiIHN0eWxlPSJmb250LXZhcmlhbnQtY2Fwczpub3JtYWw7Zm9udC12YXJpYW50LWVhc3Q' +
             'tYXNpYW46bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtdmFyaWFudC1saWdhdHVyZXM6bm9ybWFsO2ZvbnQtdmFyaWFu' +
             'dC1udW1lcmljOm5vcm1hbCI+MDwvdHNwYW4+PC90ZXh0PgogIDxnIGZvbnQtc2l6ZT0iMi44M' +
             'jNweCIgZm9udC1zdHlsZT0iaXRhbGljIiBmb250LXdlaWdodD0iYm9sZCI+CiAgIDx0ZXh0IH' +
             'g9IjMuODg3NzE5MiIgeT0iMTcuNzE5MDI3IiBzdHlsZT0ibGluZS1oZWlnaHQ6MTI1JSIgeG1' +
             'sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSI+PHRzcGFuIHg9IjMuODg3NzE5MiIgeT0iMTcuNzE5MDI3IiBm' +
             'aWxsPSIjZmZkNjE5Ij41PC90c3Bhbj48L3RleHQ+CiAgIDx0ZXh0IHg9IjguMjk4Nzg1MiIge' +
             'T0iOC41OTc4NDEzIiBzdHlsZT0ibGluZS1oZWlnaHQ6MTI1JSIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZX' +
             'J2ZSI+PHRzcGFuIHg9IjguMjk4Nzg1MiIgeT0iOC41OTc4NDEzIiBmaWxsPSIjZmZkNjE5Ij4' +
             'xMDwvdHNwYW4+PC90ZXh0PgogICA8dGV4dCB4PSIxOS44ODcxOCIgeT0iNy4xMDI1NjM5IiBz' +
             'dHlsZT0ibGluZS1oZWlnaHQ6MTI1JSIgeG1sOnNwYWNlPSJwcmVzZXJ2ZSI+PHRzcGFuIHg9I' +
             'jE5Ljg4NzE4IiB5PSI3LjEwMjU2MzkiIGZpbGw9IiNmZmQ2MTkiPjE1PC90c3Bhbj48L3RleH' +
             'Q+CiAgIDx0ZXh0IHg9IjI2LjI0MjEwNSIgeT0iMTUuOTk5NDYiIHN0eWxlPSJsaW5lLWhlaWd' +
             'odDoxMjUlIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48dHNwYW4geD0iMjYuMjQyMTA1IiB5PSIx' +
             'NS45OTk0NiIgZmlsbD0iI2ZmZDYxOSI+MjA8L3RzcGFuPjwvdGV4dD4KICAgPHRleHQgeD0iM' +
             'jQuMDczOTU0IiB5PSIyNS4wNDU4ODMiIHN0eWxlPSJsaW5lLWhlaWdodDoxMjUlIiB4bWw6c3' +
             'BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48dHNwYW4geD0iMjQuMDczOTU0IiB5PSIyNS4wNDU4ODMiIGZpbGw' +
             '9IiNmZmQ2MTkiPjI1PC90c3Bhbj48L3RleHQ+CiAgPC9nPgogPC9nPgo8L3N2Zz4K';
```

```html
<canvas width='128' height='128'></canvas><br>
<div style='display:inline-block; text-align: center'>
  <input type=range min=0 max=2500 value=0 id='rpmSlider' /><br>
  <span id='rpmOut'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: is "gagueMap" sending out the information needed to change the needle? (i have basic knowlage of coding, but i am trying to understand this code) cause then i need to add "gagueMap = data.truck.engineRpm" since "data.truck.engineRpm" is the data type (i don't know what it is called) that recieves the data from the game. and the second code part is a bit unclear. i'm used to making the background images through CSS and i am not sure what i'm supossed to do in CSS with that second code

Comment: A few quick notes. I'll answer more shortly.. The image was included like that *merely* so it would display on StackOverflow. Just include it with CSS as usual.. As it stands, there's 3 componenets to the test-page. The input-slider, the visible gague and the internal model of the gague. These 3 things do not talk to each other (data isn't sent out) I'd imagined you'd get an rpm figure, convert it to an angle, then draw the needle. There's no reason it couldn't all be combined into a single 'thing' so that you just did `gague.draw(curRpm)` when you wanted to use it. More later.